# Why is the user's input not recognized as correct?

Tags: python, string, file, python-3.x, input

my code has an issue. I'm relatively new to reading from files, and as such, I don't know what is wrong with my code.

```
# Flashcards

#Read from a file containing questions in the form question, answer


import random
import time

def __run__():
    read_file = open('state_capitals.txt','r')
    lines = read_file.readlines()
    ran_lines = random.randrange(0,49)
    string_lines = lines[ran_lines]
    global string_lines_split # To make debugging easier
    string_lines_split = string_lines.split(',')
    print(string_lines_split[1]) # Print correct answer
    usr_input = input(string_lines_split[0])
    if usr_input == str(string_lines_split[1]):
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print(usr_input)
```

When I execute **run**(), everything works fine until I enter my answer. I am prompted for an answer, and when I enter it, even if my answer is exactly the same as the answer in string_lines_split[1](http://web.mit.edu/jesstess/www/IntermediatePythonWorkshop/state_capitals.txt), the program prints that my answer is wrong. Link to text document:  http://web.mit.edu/jesstess/www/IntermediatePythonWorkshop/state_capitals.txt

```
>>>__run__()
Helena

MontanaHelena
Incorrect
Helena
```

Thank you for reading about my issue, and guiding me toward a solution. I look forward to working with the stackoverflow community.

Comment: Where is `string_lines_final` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code has error: `print(string_lines_final[1])` should be `print(string_lines_split[1])`.

Your problem is that there is a trailing `'\n'` in `string_lines_split[1]` which causes the comparison failed.

Try changing `string_lines = lines[ran_lines]` to `string_lines = lines[ran_lines].rstrip()`.

Comment: Possibly passing `"\r\n"` to `rstrip` if trailing non-newline related whitespace is important.

Comment: For future reference, how does stripping whitespace fix the code? I'm assuming that removing the whitespace converts the code to one line, and if this is correct, then will the random function work differently? I really appreciate your answer, and am trying to learn more about string methods.

Answer (score 0):

"*even if my answer is exactly the same as the answer in string_lines_split1, the program prints that my answer is wrong*"

Then they are not exactly the same. You have to accept that, because because Python can't ever bend or flex. If they're not the same but they look the same, try other things until you work out why.

Hint: how come the file is arranged like this:

```
Alabama,Montgomery
Alaska,Juneau
Arizona,Phoenix
```

instead of this:

```
Alabama,MontgomeryAlaska,JuneauArizona,Phoenix
```

?

Hint: Compare the `len()` of your input vs. the correct answer.

Hint: Compare them character by character. Maybe printing [character codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

Answer (score 0):

So when you read the file, the list returned by `read_file.readlines()` looks like this:

```
[...'West Virginia,Charleston\n', 'Wisconsin,Madison\n', 'Wyoming,Cheyenne']
```

So your code should be like this:

```
def __run__():
    read_file = open('state_capitals.txt','r')
    lines = read_file.readlines()
    ran_lines = random.randrange(0,49)
    string_lines = lines[ran_lines]
    global string_lines_split # To make debugging easier
    string_lines_split = string_lines.split(',')
    print(string_lines_split[1]) # Print correct answer
    usr_input = input(string_lines_split[0])
    if usr_input == str(string_lines_split[1].rstrip()):
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
        print(usr_input)
```